# Htdocs directorio en mac

Tags: php, apache, environment

Buen día chicos.

Estoy haciendo un repaso de `PHP` y estaba revisando que por omisión está pre instalado en `Big Sur MacOs V11.3.1`

Obtengo la versión de `PHP`

```
PHP is included in macOS for compatibility with legacy software.
Future versions of macOS will not include PHP.
PHP 7.3.24-(to be removed in future macOS) (cli) (built: Feb 28 2021 09:53:11) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.24, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

y la de apache

```
> httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.46 (Unix)
Server built:   Feb 28 2021 04:17:49
```

Mi pregunta es dónde encuentro el directorio `htdocs`?

> Entiendo que hay forma de configurar el entorno de una mejor manera. Sin embargo solo quiero realizar un repaso.

Gracias chicos encontré como lograrlo después de un tiempo pero estaba de salida y no logre actualizar.

De hecho necesite crear el directorio

> /Library/WebServer/Documents

Y me lanzó el siguiente error:

> Forbidden 403, You don’t have permission to access

Para corregirlo hay que modificar el `https.conf` del directorio de apache

> /etc/apache2/httpd.conf

y descomentar la siguiente linea

> #LoadModule php7_module libexec/apache2/libphp7.so

y posteriormente re iniciar apache

> sudo apachectl restart

[La respuesta completa en ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61098761/mac-os-catalina-webserver-error-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access)

Comment: Revisa en `/Library/WebServer/Documents`

Answer (score 1):

Hola por defecto el archivo .htaccess esta oculto en los OS de Mac es no quiere decir que no este presente en el directorio. Revisa

```
/Library/WebServer/Documents
```

y en la terminal ejecuta el comando

```
ls -la
```

Este ultimo comando listara todos archivos en el direcorio, visible y no visibles.

Answer (score 0):

instalaste directo el servicio Apache, por ende, debe de estar en el directorio `/var/www/html/`,  puedes hacer en tu terminal lo siguiente:

1. `ls /var/www/html` lista el contenido de la carpeta de apache.
2. `netstat -ntlp` con dicho comando, podras ver los servicios activo dentro de maquina.